# Using Autofac in the class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ioc-container, autofac

i'm trying to solve a problem with the Autofac IoC container.

My web application has the following parts:

1. Web application
2. Core (shared) library.
3. Modules

Each module has a reference to the core library (that includes the code below) and each module must be able to register their own types. Therefore i need to have one shared container between application and modules.

I have the following container's code:

```
public static class DependencyContainer
    {
        public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public static ContainerBuilder Builder { get; private set; }

        public static void RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom
        {
            Builder.RegisterType<TTo>().As<TFrom>();
        }

        public static T ResolveType<T>()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        public static void InitContainer()
        {
            Builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            Container = Builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

This container is located in the main (core) library. When application starts it calls InitContainer() from global.asax. After this i'm trying to register a new type from my application modules using RegisterType() method.

But after this i can not resolve any types. It just throws an exception that this type wasn't registered.

The main idea of this code is that i'm going to be able to resolve any type from any module and web application using only one shared container.

Can somebody help me with this problem? Is there a more elegant architectural solution for using one shared IoC container between multiple libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your design leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Prevent from defining a container in the core library and letting everybody reference it. Use dependency injection and configure the container in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), your start-up path of the application (in your case the composition root will be part of your Web Application).

You can take advantage of the [Autofac Module feature](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules), and in the composition root, you can register this module.

```
builder.RegisterModule(new CarTransportModule());
```

But you can define your module registration classes as static as well, which is even simpler:

```
MyApp.SomeModule.SomeModuleBootstrapper.Register(builder);
```

Comment: +1 for using the modules. I would however use Reflection to find and load all modules

Comment: As I show in my answer, just by calling a static method. This way there is no need for any container specific infrastructure. Of course this doesn't work when you need to dynamically load 'modules', but most applications don't need this.

Comment: That moves the responsibility from the code that needs to register stuff to the code that creates the container. In reflection we should trust ;)

Comment: @jgauffin: there is not really much difference. The registration code is still located at the same place, and either way, in your composition root you will need custom code to trigger this registration. And your composition root already has a reference to all those sub systems, because the composition root knows everything.

Comment: I just meant `builder.RegisterAllModules()` when using something like https://gist.github.com/2781196

Comment: I like a modular system and we already have such infrastructure for modules where each module has a bootstrapper that registers it's dependencies. Bootstrapper inherits from the AbstractModule class that have a special method: RegisterDependencies (this method is calling from global.asax for each module). It means that each module should register its services by itself. Web application shouldn make it. Therefore i should keep DI container accessible from each module and application...

Comment: Your conclusion "Therefore i should keep DI container accessible from each module" is invalid. You still don't have to store the container as singleton accessible to all the code. Just pass it on to the modules as method argument, or use the Autofac Module facility. This prevents you from letting application code accessing the container.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved - we need to call container.Build() only AFTER registration of all our dependencies...

Comment: +1 while the other discussion about service locators and modules is interesting (and important), it's not the problem at hand